# Using generics in flutter to create a generic http call with a Json deserializer

Tags: flutter, generics

I tried to extend model classes with my custom `JsonSerializable` that contains a `fromJson(Map<String dynamic> json)`. I thought that would make it very easy to create any number of http calls since I only have to define my model type on `getDataOfUrl<ModelClass>("/api/example/")` but the problem is that I cannot create an object from `T`. Is there any way to fix this or is there an alternative way?

```
Future<T> getDataOfUrl<T extends JsonSerializable>(String url) async {
  logger.i("Fetching data $url");
  final response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse('$baseUri$url'));

  final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
  final object = (dynamic as T).fromJson(responseData as Map<String, dynamic>);
  return object;
}
```

I already tried different ways to create an object from `T`. I also tried to return the data directly but it does not work.

Comment: [There are many questions just like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdart%5D+t.fromjson). `static` methods and constructors in Dart are not part of a type's interface. I strongly recommend using [`package:json_serializable`](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) or [`package:built_value`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) and not implementing your own serialization/deserialization code. Alternatively pass around a `fromJson` callback appropriate for that type.